# How to configure and install nano server using DSC powershell on Windows server 2019

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-powershell, dsc, nano-server

I have Windows Server 2019, where I want to setup  Nano Server installation and Docker using DSC powershell scripts.

This requirement is for Azure VM using State Configuration from Azure Automation.

The Script

configuration Myconfig
{
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName DockerMsftProvider

```
{
Ensure = 'present'
Module_Name = 'DockerMsftProvider'
Repository = 'PSGallery'
}
```

}

I know, I am missing few parameters here.. please help me in completing this script

Similarly, I need it to setup Nano server if possible.

Comment: Can you provide more details on your requirements?

Comment: I have added my requirements